# C Library For Quickly Writing CLI Programs

Tags: windows, linux, command-line, c

I'm working on porting most of my PHP, Python, and Bash scripts over to C.

As a "beginner" with the C language I am overwhelmed with the documentation and all the memory management shenanigans one has to deal with.

Because I am mostly familiar with PHP and its almost verbose function names, I am interested in a library that has similar naming scheme (doesn't have to be the exact same as PHP).

Many of my scripts do very simple operations which I can run from my terminal, some of those are:

- Removing all non-ASCII characters in a file
- Prefixing file names with a leading zero
- cd-ing into a git repository directory and calling a couple of git commands
- Fetching Torrent trackers from a GitHub repository and writing into the clipboard

the list goes on...

Ideally it would be beneficial if the library is compatible with both Windows and Linux environments.